# Failed to update record in MySQL table using jsp

Tags: jquery, mysql, jsp

I am trying to update record in MySQL database table (dmsfiles) using JSP. But I am not getting output also no error occurred.

I tried below code to update record. **When I click on Update button then nothing printed** only Home button displayed. Update query is not executing. What am I getting wrong?

**filelist.jsp**

```html
<%
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms","root","");
String zid = request.getParameter("zid");
String sql = "select * from dmsfiles where zid= '"+zid+"'";
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
while(rs.next()){
 %>

 ...

<th class="text-center">Edit Form</th>
...
<td>  <a href="editnew.jsp?zid=<%=rs.getString("zid")%>&documentname=<%=rs.getString(9)%>" class="btn btn-warning">Edit</a></td>
```

**editnew.jsp**

```html
<%
String host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms";
Statement stat = null;
ResultSet res = null;
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement stmt = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host,"root","");
stat = conn.createStatement();
String docName = request.getParameter("documentname");
String zid = request.getParameter("zid");
String data = "select * from dmsfiles where zid = '"+zid+"' AND document_name = '"+docName+"'";
res = stat.executeQuery(data);
while(res.next()){
%>
...
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="Update" name="update" class="btn btn-primary"/>
</td>
</tr>
```

**editprocess.jsp**

```html
<%@page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
String z_id = request.getParameter("zid");
String first_Name = request.getParameter("firstname");
String last_Name = request.getParameter("lastname");
String mail_i_d = request.getParameter("mailid");
String d_iv = request.getParameter("division");
String de_pt = request.getParameter("department");
String cost_centercode = request.getParameter("costcentercode");
String doc_num = request.getParameter("documentnumber");   String doc_Name = request.getParameter("documentname");

...

String file_Name = "";
String folder_Name = "allfiles";
String pa_th = folder_Name + File.separator + file_Name;
Timestamp add_ed_date = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()); 
            
            
if(request.getParameter("update") != null){
   Connection con = null;
   PreparedStatement ps = null;
   try{
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dmsqms","root","");
       String sql = "update dmsfiles set firstname=?,lastname=?,mailid=?,division=?,department=?,costcentercode=?,document_number=?,document_name=?,document_type=?,document_category=?,document_classification=?,authorised_by=?,fromdate=?,todate=?,document_level=?,document_general=?,serial_number=?,revision_number=?,issuer=?,status=?,filename=?,path=?,added_date=? where zid='"+z_id+"'"; 
      ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1,z_id);
      ps.setString(2,first_Name);
      ps.setString(3,last_Name);
      ps.setString(4,mail_i_d);
      ps.setString(5,d_iv);
      ps.setString(6,de_pt);
      ps.setString(7,cost_centercode);
      ps.setString(8,doc_num);
      ps.setString(9,doc_Name);
      
      ...
      
      ps.setString(22,file_Name);
      ps.setString(23,pa_th);
      ps.setTimestamp(24, null);
      int i = ps.executeUpdate();
      if(i > 0)
      {
       //out.print("Record Updated Successfully");
        out.println("alert('Record Updated Successfully');");
      }
      else
      {
      //out.print("There is a problem in updating Record.");
      out.println("alert('There is a problem in updating Record.');");
      }
     }
     catch(SQLException sql)
     {
      request.setAttribute("error", sql);
      out.println(sql);
      }
      }
      %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<title>editprocess jsp Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="home.jsp" class="btn btn-info">Home</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: help me with this

Comment: In your update query there are `23` columns and when you set value for them you have `24` ?  Also not even `out.println("alert('There is a problem in updating.` this gets printed ? Also check what `request.getParameter("update")` have in it ?

Comment: I have added Update button in editnew.jsp and using this button into editprocess.jsp as request.getParameter("update")

Comment: Why are you setting your connection in jsp. It would be much better to do this in a separate class.  Furthermore enable your logging to find out if the query is getting executed or not. Are you using any framework for this?

Answer (score 0):

add editnew.jsp in form tag and

```
<input type="hidden" value="update" name="update"/>
<input type="submit" value="Update" class="btn btn-primary"/>
```

remove name from submit input.
Because your not passing `update` parameter in req so  `if(request.getParameter("update") != null)` will evaluate false and your query in will not execute.